# Prove a complement of a union and intersection of two sets?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

So our teacher asked us to prove that $(A\cup B) \setminus (A \cap B)$ = $(A \cap \overline{B}) \cup (\overline{A} \cap B)$

Obviously the statement makes sense when I look at it, but actually proving/explaining why they are equal eludes me.  Could I get some help?

Comment: Let $x$ be in the first set and from this show this implies it is in the second. Now do it the other way round and this proves they're equal. Another way to prove this is to draw venn diagrams for both sides and they will be the same

Comment: Venn diagrams never constitute a proof. They are an intuitive tool.

Comment: If you label your venn diagram correctly,  they lead to an if and only if proof directly.  But yes, the usual way one shows two sets are equal is to show that they are subsets of each other.

Answer (score 1):

If $x\in (A\cup B)\backslash (A\cap B)$ then, $x\in A\cup B$ and $x\notin A\cap B$. It follows that $x\in A$ or $x\in B$. If $x\in A$, then $x\notin B$ and thus $x\in A\cap \overline B$. If $x\in B$, then $x\notin A$ and thus $x\in B\cap \overline A$. Thus $x\in (A\cap \overline B)\cup (\overline A \cap B)$.

This is half of the proof.